# probability about animals being moved

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, percentages, binomial-distribution

I have this scenario:

> 1 animal with $30\%$ probability of be moved to Japan. 
>  1 animal with
>   $30\%$ probability of be moved to Japan. 
>  1 animal with $30\%$
>   probability of be moved to Japan. 
>  1 animal with $30\%$ probability
>   of be moved to Japan. 
>  1 animal with $30\%$ probability of be moved
>   to Japan. 
>  1 animal with $30\%$ probability of be moved to Japan.
>   
>  1 animal with $30\%$ probability of be moved to China. 
>  1 animal
>   with 30% probability of be moved to Japan. 
>  1 animal with $80\%$
>   probability of be moved to Brazil. 
>  1 animal with $30\%$ probability
>   of be moved to Japan. 
>  1 animal with $20\%$ probability of be moved
>   to Brazil. 
>  1 animal with $30\%$ probability of be moved to Japan.
>   
>  1 animal with $50\%$ probability of be moved to Mexico. 
>  1
>   animal with $30\%$ probability of be moved to Japan. 
>  (...)

Resuming, $10$ animals with $30\%$ of the probability of being moved to Japan.

Is that "right" to expect that $3$ animals gonna be moved to Japan?

The formula is:
$30/100 \cdot 10 = 3$

Can I use **Binomial Distribution** for this scenario?
If yes, how to elaborate the formula?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The binomial distribution requires that all events have the same probability. The set-up here is new to me. I see that all the animals going to Japan have the same probability, so if the problem is restricted to them, it is possible. With $n=10$ animals, given the probability and the number $r=3$ that go, the rest is plug-and-chug.

Comment: Mandata, the events have the same probability, because it's about the 10 animals with 30% of probability about being moved to Japan. Do you know how to apply the formula? Thanks!

Comment: It is straightforward.  You have three values: one is a probability, a number of trials (# of animals), and a number of successes (going to Japan).  Look at the equation and figure out what goes where.  You can do it for sure.